# Compressing using Bzip2 on-the-fly to a file?

Tags: ruby, csv, bzip2

There is a program that generates huge CSV files. For example:

```
arr = (0..10).to_a
CSV.open("foo.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  (2**16).times { csv << arr }
end
```

It will generate a big file, so I want to be compressed ***on-the-fly***, and, instead of output a non-compressed CSV file (`foo.csv`), output a bzip-compressed CSV file (`foo.csv.bzip`).

I have an example from the "ruby-bzip2" gem:

```
writer = Bzip2::Writer.new File.open('file')
writer << 'data1'
writer.close
```

I am not sure how to compose Bzip2 write from the CSV one.

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you asking: do you want to eliminate the bzip file creation or the csv file creation? or other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also construct a `CSV` object with an IO or something sufficiently like an IO, such as a `Bzip2::Writer`.

For example

```
File.open('file.bz2', 'wb') do |f|
  writer = Bzip2::Writer.new f
  CSV(writer) do |csv|
    (2**16).times { csv << arr }
  end
  writer.close
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be more flexible to write the CSV data to *stdout*:

```
# csv.rb
require 'csv'
$stdout.sync = true

arr = (0..10).to_a
(2**16).times do
  puts arr.to_csv
end
```

... and pipe the output to `bzip2`:

```
$ ruby csv.rb | bzip2 > foo.csv.bz2
```

Comment: Of course, this is a pretty solution, but I need to do all processing with ruby. You solution using bash is pretty good. Anyway thank you.

Comment: *WHY* does all processing have to be done in Ruby? It's a more standard (which means well-tested), and flexible, practice to pipe the output into a compressing app.